# sudo minikube returns “command not found”

Tags: sudo

I need to run minikube as sudo on Centos 7.5. minikube is in /usr/local/bin

For my user echo $PATH is:

```
/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
```

For user root echo $PATH is:

```
/usr/local/bin/:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

I even added the following to visudo

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

But still...

```
sudo minikube start --cpus 4 --memory 24000 --disk-size=50g --kubernetes-version=v1.7.4 --vm-driver=none
```

returns sudo: minikube: command not found

What is wrong, or whatelse is missing?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

See this issue for the answer: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1932

The problem is because your minikube is installed to `/usr/bin/local` and sudo does not see the binary. A simple fix is to do:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/local/minikube /usr/bin/
```

Comment: Faced the same issue but the dir in my case was /usr/local/bin/* instead of /usr/bin/local/*

Comment: When I do this:
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/minikube /usr/bin/   I see error below
mv: rename /usr/local/bin/minikube to /usr/bin/minikube: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Minikube was installed in `/usr/bin/local/minikube`
so I typed:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/local/minikube /usr/bin/
```

You need to check where the Minikube is installed first (`whereis minikube`) and then move it to `/usr/bin/`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Binaries installed in `/usr/bin/local`, PATH contains `/usr/local/bin` (traditional place for local/experimental/non-official stuff, check). PATH for root (!!!) has local stuff *before* the system locations (basic sanity is to have root with a minimal PATH, *never* including '.' nor unofficial stuff). Fix that first.